# Angular - Sending a value with button press

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a chord player in Angular, and for each button, would like to send a value with the particular chord.  I wondering what the best way of doing this is.

In my index.html

```
<button class="chord-btn" ng-option="c" model="note" ng-click="ctrl.changeChord(note)">C major</button>
```

And in my controller.js....

```
app.controller('ChordController', [function() {

var self = this;

self.changeChord = function(note) {
  alert("Chord to be played is"+ note);
};
}]);
```

Currently when I click the button, the alert says that the note 'is undefined'.  Would greatly appreciate anyones thoughts, I am new to Angular and suspect I am doing something silly.

Comment: Where is the `note` defined in your controller?

Comment: what is the value of `note` ?

Comment: Where does `note` come from? ngRepeat? Post complete HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  At present, the value of the note for this should be 'c' ( for C major).  I have used ng-option for this (perhaps incorrectly ?)

Comment: ng-click="ctrl.changeChord('c')" if u just need the letter passed through that should work. I am not sure about ng-option, ng-options is used for selects normally tho.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject $scope in your controller. $scope is the glue between your view and your controller. Then, add your function to the $scope object. The following code should do the trick.

```
app.controller('ChordController', function($scope) {

    $scope.changeChord = function(note) {
        alert("Chord to be played is"+ note);
    };
});
```

Comment: OP's using controller-as syntax, he doesn't need `$scope`.